# Why default template suggestion use double dash instead of single dash?

Tags: 7, theming

```
block--module--delta.tpl.php
page--front.tpl.php
```

As above example, what is the reason behind double dash? Why not use single dash like `page-front.tpl.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe it's just to add separation on the off-chance that the region/content type/page name has a dash in it, itself. `block--my-impressive-module--delta.tpl.php` is a lot easier to see that the intended target is `block` named `my-impressive-module`, than if it were `block-my-impressive-module-delta.tpl.php` (now there's no separation between the three name sections). It's possible for a region/content type/page name to have a dash, but none will have two dashes, so it's a reasonable substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal uses this convention to determine what file to use. If the name contains a double-underscore ('__') and there isn't an implementation for the full name, the part before the '__' is checked. This allows a fallback to a more generic implementation.

Drupal converts double unscores to dashes, for example when a template suggestion is created in code you would do the following:

```
$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__something';
```

The template for this is...

```
page--something.tpl.php
```

If 'page--something' can't be found it will default to...

```
page.tpl.php
```

If your page was 'products page' for example your template would be...

```
page--products-page.tpl.php
```

The single dash acts a space.

Comment: While that's part of the answer, that doesn't explain why the underscores are double.

Comment: Hm, didn't know that ...